# Does PrinterWriter creates a file if it doesn't exists?

Tags: java, arrays, java-io, printwriter

I am using `PrintWriter object` file as below:

```
PrintWriter pwriter = new PrintWriter("abc.txt");
```

Please let me know if a file name `abc.txt` will be created if it doesn't exist.

I have tried it and it is not creating file. But i want to confirm if it is the expected not to create the file.

Comment: read the documentation of `PrintWriter` to know more details

Comment: @Blip Rubbish. It will create the file immediately. Don't post misinformation or guesswork here.

Comment: Since you specified a relative path name, make sure you are looking **in the current directory for the (JVM) process** executing this code. Especially if you are running from an IDE or any kind of platform like a webserver or appserver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.lang.String-):

> fileName - The name of the file to use as the destination of this writer. If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size; **otherwise, a new file will be created**. The output will be written to the file and is buffered.